# Django: Use select_related without a ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models which are used with a database I don't control. Both are set with `managed = False`. The first model has a field which is a foreign key to the second model, but it's implemented as a `CharField`, not as a `ForeignKey`.

Is it possible to use `select_related` on the first model to access properties of the key'd second model?

Here's an example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    fieldone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    myfk = models.CharField(max_length=20) # In practice, this points to Bar.localkey

class Bar(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    localkey = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    someotherattribute = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Foo.objects.all().select_related('Bar') # I know this won't work, but is there something that will?
```

Comment: Why can't you use `ForeignKey`?

Comment: I thought I wouldn't be able to use a ForeignKey because the actual database that this model is using is out of my control (hence `managed=False`). However, even though this relationship is not implemented as a true foreign key in that database, using a ForeignKey did seem to work here and I am now able to use `select_related`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because there's nothing related.

But if you (or someone for some reason) have stored the ID (or some unique value such as `localkey`) from the 'related' object,  you could perform a filter based on it.

```
foo = Foo.objects.first()  # Pick one Foo object
foo_bar = Bar.objects.get(localkey=foo.myfk)
```

To make this looks like `select_related` you could try this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
    fieldone = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    myfk = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def bar(self):
        return Bar.objects.get(localkey=self.myfk)
        # probably you will need to manage common error when performing a .get()
        # DoesNotExist and MultipleObjectsReturned
```

Then use like this:

```
foos = Foo.objects.all()

for foo in foos:
    print foo.bar()
```

**I am not sure if this is a good idea** but you could decorate `.bar()` method as a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
...

@property
def bar(self):
    return Bar.objects.get(localkey=self.myfk)
```

And then call it like this:

```
foo  # some random Foo object
foo.bar  # this should return the 'related' Bar object
```

Comment: It would hit extra db query while getting instance of `Bar` for every instance of `foos` though. Its defeating the purpose of using `select_related` since join data is not catched. I think raw sql would have been more upto the mark.

Comment: Not really an answer for this question. `select_related` adds a `JOIN` and a bunch of fields to `SELECT`. The point of it is to *not* cause additional DB hits afterwards. This answer will do exactly that - cause a DB hit for every object in the queryset when accessing its `.bar` property (or method).